# Como funciona o firebase para envio de notificações?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Esta pergunta não tem haver com códigos e sim entender o funcionamento do firebase.

Quero montar um sistema que notifique o usuário em um app Android através de um web service PHP. Pelo o que pesquisei, o jeito mais fácil é utilizando o firebase(e funcionou perfeitamente comigo), porém queria montar um webservice independente.

A minha dúvida é :

Como o firebase notifica o celular? Pelo o que vi, podemos fazer para que o celular verifique se há alguma notificação a cada X minutos, porém isso não consumiria bastante tráfego de dados?

Como o firebase notifica o usuário instantaneamente?
Queria entender esta lógica, para evitar que o usuário fique checando que há novas notificações a cada X minutos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funciona exactamente como você está pensando: um serviço no dispositivo mantém uma ligação com os servidores da Google.

A diferença fundamental é que esse serviço serve vários servidores/clientes, todos aqueles que sobrescreveram o serviço, e não apenas o seu servidor/cliente.

Ao ter um serviço único, que serve vários servidores e disponibiliza/distribui as mensagens a vários clientes, permite que o tráfico seja usado de forma mais eficiente em vez de cada cliente/servidor ter o seu próprio serviço.

```
                ------------        ------------        ------------
                |Servidor A|        |Servidor B|        |Servidor C|
                ------------        ------------        ------------
                     |                    |                   |
                     |                    |                   |
                     ---------------------|--------------------
                                          |
                                       -------
                                       | FCM |
                                       ------- 
                                          |
                                          |
                       -------------------|--------------------
                       |                  |                   |
                ---------------     ---------------     ---------------
                |Dispositivo 1|     |Dispositivo 2|     |Dispositivo 3|
                ---------------     ---------------     ---------------
                   |        |          |        |              |       
                -------  -------    -------  -------        -------
                |App 1|  |App 2|    |App 1|  |App 2|        |App 2|
                -------  -------    -------  -------        -------
```

O [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) serve de intermediário entre o seu servidor e o os dispositivos.
Ele é responsável por receber as mensagens, geri-las e encaminhá-las para os respectivo dispositivos.

Comment: Obrigado,Resposta esclareceu o funcionamento.Agora poderia me informar se é uma má prática fazer um service própio chamado a cada x minutos para verificar notificação em vez de usar o firebase ?

Comment: Não propriamente. O único problema é aquele que você já identificou: consumir mais tráfego de dados, e consumir recursos(memória e cpu) do dispositivo.

Answer (score 0):

Você vai, no lado servidor(no seu caso em PHP), após algum evento (por exemplo, no fim do seu método de salvar usuário no servidor), chamar a biblioteca do firebase para enviar uma mensagem push para um usuário através de um identificador único (disponibilizado pela biblioteca do firebase no device). Exemplo em nodejs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages?hl=pt-br.

No device (IOS, ANDROID...), você irá implementar um método onMessage (disponibilizado pela biblioteca do firebase no device), que automáticamente será disparado ao chegar um push para o indentificador único deste aparelho. Exemplo para um client Javascrip: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive?hl=pt-br.

Comment: Olá,obrigado pela ajuda,porém como dito no tópico,já consegui utilizar o firebase pra enviar notificação,a dúvida é,como o firebase notifica o celular sem o celular ficar atualizando de x em x minutos.